# compare two generic objects on swift 2.0

Tags: swift, swift2

I have to establish whether the current value is equal to the given comparing value.

```
public static func Is<TBaseValue, TComparingValue>(baseValue: TBaseValue, comparingValue: TComparingValue) -> Bool
{
    return baseValue == comparingValue
}
```

I almost try this

```
public static func Is<TBaseValue: Comparable, TComparingValue: Comparable>(baseValue: TBaseValue, comparingValue: TComparingValue) -> Bool
{
    return baseValue==comparingValue
}
```

and this

```
  public static func Is<TBaseValue: Equatable, TComparingValue: Equatable>(baseValue: TBaseValue, comparingValue: TComparingValue) -> Bool
{
    return baseValue == comparingValue
}
```

but always I have the same result Binary operator cannot be applied....

Comment: It works with known types. Show your definitions of `TBaseValue` and `TComparingValue`.

Answer (score 2):

`Equatable` doesn't exactly mean that. Think about things that are equatable - `Int`, for instance. `2 == 2` makes sense. `2 == 3` will return `false` - but it still makes sense. Now, think of something else that's `Equatable` - `String`, for instance.

```
"abc" == "abc" // true
"acb" == "abc" // false
```

That's fine - but what about this:

```
"abc" == 4
```

An `Equatable` thing is `Equatable` to itself - not to everything else. In your example, you're comparing two different types - `TBaseValue, TComparingValue`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare any values you can use overloading:

```
static func Is<T: Equatable>(first: T, second: T) -> Bool {
    return first == second
}

static func Is<T1, T2>(first: T1, second: T2) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

So the most appropriate function gets called automatically. If the first function cannot be called with the passed parameters than the second one gets called anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

This works in Swift 2.0.

```
func Is<Any : Equatable>(l: Any, _ r: Any) -> Bool {
    return l == r
}

Is("a", "a") // true
Is("a", "b") // false
Is(1, 1)     // true
```

It also would work with `AnyObject`.

Answer (score 0):

For comparing two generics, you can declare the generics such that, types, that are capable to be in the place of your generic type, should conform to [Comparable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/comparable) protocol.

```
struct Heap<T: Comparable>{
var heap = [T]()
mutating func insert(element: T){
heap.append(element)
var index = heap.count - 1
heapify(childIndex: index)
}}
```

Now we will be able to do:-

```
if heap[parentIndex] < heap[childIndex] {
//Your code
}
```

How this works?

As we know, conforming to a protocol means implementing all the required methods in that protocol. **Comparable** protocol has got all the comparison methods as required parameters, and any type that is implementing **Comparable** will be able to do a comparison.

Happy coding using Generics